# Potential bug that creates white black patches on the mesh + warps mesh behaviour and destroys it upon sculpting

Tags: modeling

Unsure if a known issue, nor do I know how I managed to do this.

Part of the mesh changes to black and white patches when I enter sculpt mode, Pre-entering sculpt mode, the material has slightly off norm properties that would normally be in cycles. Mesh cant be texture painted either. Second time it has happened in a long period, accidently saved this time though.

Is there a fix or ?

[image]